# Comparing elements without storing them in a vector, array, list, etc

Tags: c++, list, vector, header, element

Alright, so I've always struggled with this in programming, and now, I'm starting on a very difficult programming assignment and this is *suppose* to be one of the easier portions of the assignment... but basically, here's what I'm supposed to do (I'll copy and paste the prompt, and then write what it means, just to clarify):

> Your first task is to write a template for an accumulator, InOrder, that
>   accepts a sequence of items via a .put(item) method and returns true or false via a .get() method indicating whether the sequence is in order.

Alright, so it's probably not difficult for some of you, but basically what I'm supposed to do is write the header code for this class, then it uses this method:

```
// The put method of anAccumulator has been applied
// to all values accessed by interators begin up to end.
template<typename A, typename I>
void
apply(A & anAccumulator, I begin, I end)
{
    for (I iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        anAccumulator.put( *iter);
    }
}
```

and here is what I've got so far for my TInOrder.h header file:

```
// Declares the class for InOrder.

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#ifndef __INORDER_H_
#define __INORDER_H_

template <typename T>
class InOrder
{
public:
    InOrder() : _count(0)
    {};

    void put(T item)
    {
        data = item;

        while (item < data)
        {
            yOrder = true;
        }
    }

    bool get()
    {
        if (yOrder == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

private:
    bool yOrder;
    bool _count;
    T data;
};

#endif
```

obviously, I've got no clue what I'm doing. But, to my understanding, I'm supposed to use the .put() and .get() methods in some manner without a list, vector, stack, or queue. Here's what my TA wrote to me in an e-mail, I think he better explains it than I do:

> I hope this helps. From the instructions in your email it doesn't seem like your class needs to get its input from the command line. You just need to define the .put() method. (i.e) your class doesn't care where the input comes from. Now since your class only gets one input at a time, I'm sure you'll be able to figure out how to tell if the sequence seen so far is *in order* or not and you don't even need to store all the values seen so far. Do not use a vector, list or any other container for this.

So my real question is: how do you use the .put() method to test whether or not the user input is in order? I'm really struggling to figure all of this out, and I hope someone can help me understand the logic behind it. I know it's supposed to be something involving comparison and overwriting, but not much more than that. An example would be great. I appreciate it so much, thank you!

Comment: Whenever you find yourself not understand what you are doing, consider restart your thinking process and begin with "what do I want to do".

Comment: All of that text to say "how do I remember one value and write one if statement?"

Comment: @NickyC: I get that I want to store the current value in a variable, compare it to the next value, and then continue traversing the user input without storing it in a container. I just need help coming up with the code for something like that, I just don't understand why I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You can and should replace `if (yOrder == true){return true;} else {return false;}` with `return yOrder;`. If you don't understand why then think about it until you do understand, as this is important

Comment: @M.M: Gotcha. I can see if it's true than it's true, or if it's false, it'll return false. I got that. My .put() method cannot be right though, and that is where I need the most guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to keep the old value and compare new item with it.

Assuming that `T` is default contructible and copyable:

```
template <typename T>
class InOrder
{
public:
    InOrder() : inOrder(true), initialized(false), oldValue() {}

    void put(const T& item)
    {
        if (initialized && item < oldValue) {
            inOrder = false;
        }
        oldValue = item;
        initialized = true;
    }
    bool get() const { return inOrder; }

private:
    bool inOrder;
    bool initialized;
    T oldValue;
};
```

`boost::optional<T>` may replace `bool initialized; T oldValue;`.